# VBA how to initialize vCPath

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How do I initialize vCPath?

[VBA Run-Time Error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979650/vba-run-time-error-1004)

@Garry's Student says I "must somehow use the info you get from Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) to generate the full filespec of the file you wish to open".

What's the simplest way to do this? I am a VBA beginner: I have been programming VBA for about a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code you've got this block:

```
' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

'   Display paths of each file selected
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    Next lngCount
    For Each strFilename In .SelectedItems
        MsgBox strFilename
    Next
End With
```

Which already does what you want. The `strFilename` variable is the path and filename of the files selected by the user. Put the rest of your code into another proc and then call the new proc passing it the `strFilename` variable.

```
' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

'   Display paths of each file selected
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    Next lngCount
    For Each strFilename In .SelectedItems
        someSensibleProcName strFilename
    Next
End With

Private Sub someSensibleProcName (ByRef pathAndNameOfFile As String)

Dim sourceBook As Workbook

    ' Some of your code here

    Set sourceBook = Workbooks.OpenText (Filename:=pathAndNameOfFile _
        , Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
        Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)

    ' The rest of your code here
    End Sub
```